# Simplified "for loop" syntax in c#

Tags: c#, loops, syntax, for-loop

I want to use C# to **build a custom-made scripting language**. It will have simple statements which are in fact method calls with arguments like:

```
Set("C1", 63);
Wait(1.5);
Incr("C1", 1);
```

Now, I want to provide also a **loop** and the usual C# syntax with the indexer is too complicated for such a simple thing. For example I would have this to loop 20 times:

```
for (20)
{
  Wait(1.5);
  Incr("C1", 1);      
}
```

**Is there some way to achieve such a simple loop at least closely?** (e.g. a wrapped method call inside the for statement or the like)

Thanks, Marcel

Comment: `for(20)`, which I would rather call `repeat(20)`, would be equivalent in C# with `for(int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)`. I don't understand what is the actual problem.

Comment: My problem is, that I feel the standard for statement too complicated for my scripting language. In fact id encapsulates 3 statements with a lot of special characters, to express something that could be told with a single number. My users will be non-programmers.

Comment: In the end, I used IronPython. Not exactly a very simple language, but more known to my users, and still reasonably simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a function extending ints:

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static void Times(this int n, Action action) {
        if (action != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
                action();
    }

}
```

call it like:

```
20.Times(() => {
    Wait(1.5);
    Incr("C1", 1);
});
```

Comment: I'll accept that because it is short in code and quite elegant.

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with delegates and lambda expressions.

```
For(20, () => 
    { 
        Wait(1.5); 
        Incr("C1", 1); 
    } );

private void For (int count, Action action)
{
    while (count-- > 0)
        action();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 public static class Loop{
     public static void For(int iterations, Action actionDelegate){       
         for (int i = 1; i <= iterations; i++) actionDelegate();
     }
 }
```

Example:

```
class ForLoopTest 
{
    static void Main() 
    {
       Loop.For(20, () => { Wait(1.5); Incr("C1",1); }); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us understand, a script code like this:

```
Declare("myVar", "integer");
Set("myVar", "5");

For("myVar"){Say("Hello");}
```

Will be interpreted like something like this:

```
public class MyScriptInterpreter
{

  // ...

  protected void forLoop(List<String> Params; List<String> Block)
  {
    int HowManyTimes = Convert.ToInt16(Params[0]);

    for (int k=1; k == HowManyTimes; k++) 
    {
       interpretBlock(Block);
    } 
  }


  protected void interpretBlock(List<String> Block)
  {
    foreach(String eachInstruction in Block)
    {
       interpret(eachInstruction);
    }
  }

  protected void interpret
     (String Instruction, List<String> Params; MyDelegateType MyDelegate)
  {
    if (Instruction == "declare")
    {
      this.declare(Params);
    }
    else if (Instruction == "set")
    {
      this.set(Params);
    }
    else if (Instruction == "for")
    {
      this.forLoop(Params, MyDelegate);
    }
  }
} // class
```

So, the block of the for, becomes a list of instructions, maybe strings.

Anyway, as an additional answer, I suggest to think to add, in the future, functions (procedures, subroutines) and namespaces (modules) to your language, as a required syntax.

I know that its a little difficult to implement. But, I have seen a lot of script languages that eventually, are use from small code snippets to full applications, and the lack of functions or namespaces make a mess.

```
ScriptBegin("FiveTimes");
   Declare("myVar", "integer");
   Set("myVar", "5");

   For("myVar"){Say("Hello");}
ScriptEnd();
```

PHP its a good example of this problem. Started, just like your script, for quick small applications. Eventually, functions and namespace where added.

Good Luck with your project.